# shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate used for Objective-C method call

Tags: javascript, objective-c, dom-events, hybrid

I am trying to call a Objective-C method from Javascript. I am not using any libraries such as phonegap and I have also succeeded in calling the Objective-C method but for that I am creating a iframe each time before the call then only the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate is invoked I just followed the below links:

[UIWebView Secrets](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/)

[UIWebView JavaScript to Objective-C communication](http://blog.grio.com/2012/07/uiwebview-javascript-to-objective-c-communication.html)

But how to make a Objective-C method call without invoking the webview delegate `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`?

Comment: The problem is that your only gate between your javascript and your application is the `UIWebView` and if you want to send something to your app, it will have to go through the shouldStartLoadWithRequest, which is where you catch it using the iframe thing. I'm pretty sure there's no way around it

Comment: thanks for your comment but i am trying to make my js common to all platforms

Comment: hi Ismael i totally agree of wat u said

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a pretty big problem. I'm developing a rather large hybrid solution right now, and it's important to understand how the native part of the hybrid app works on all your target platforms before you can make your js common to all platforms.

The shouldStartLoadWithRequest method depends on using custom URLs to communicate from the webpage to the native code. Clicking on a link, say hybrid://showMenu will try to open the link in the webview, and the delegate will intercept this call in shouldStartLoadWithRequest. At that point, you will recognize the call and perform whatever actions you want, eg show a menu and tell the webview to stop the loading.

There is an equivalent function on both BlackBerry (at least before v10) and Android, and most likely Windows Phone. PhoneGap is using this technique across the platforms. All of these functions will be able to catch the hybrid://showMenu call. They all behave in a different way and you'll have to do research on your own to get the code, but I can confirm that it is absolutely possible to use the same Javascript in different native shells.

You are correct to use iframes to speed up the Javascript, but there are other tricks you'll need to do to get the best performance. They differ for each browser, so if you want the best performance your Javascript will have to differ at least a little bit across platforms. Here's a good article on how to get good performance on iOS:

[iOS Hybrid App primer from CocoaControls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/posts/a-primer-on-hybrid-apps-for-ios)

Now, if you still want to avoid using the URLs and webview delegate to communicate between JS and native code, you could go with the much more complicated route of using WebSockets.

For this, you would have to include a WebSocket server library in each of your native wrappers that would listen to local connections. Then your Javascript would include a WebSocket client library that it would use to pass messages to the native code. Two way communication is possible. Your JS will be more or less the same across platforms.

I haven't implemented this method myself because it's overkill for what I need, but LinkdIn's hybrid app is using it. More info here:

[LinkdIn's Hybrid App diary](http://engineering.linkedin.com/mobile/linkedin-ipad-nativeweb-messaging-bridge-and-websockets)

If you go with (2) good luck and please share your results.